# One task to send & receive UDP frames to itself

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp

I wrote an application that's meant to send UDP packets to itself.
I spawn separate threads, one that's handling the Tx side of things and another one that's handling the Rx side. However, it seems like the Tx frames is transmitting frames but I can not see my `recvfrom()` being unblocked to receive ta data. Is there something basic I'm missing, this should be possible, right? 
The Tx method is invoked repeatedly every 1 second and the Rx thread is started before the Tx thread becomes alive.
Some code pieces I can provide are how I open my Tx&Rx sockets:
**Tx**:

```
int network::sendUDP(BfdDat* pDat)
{
    const char* hostname=0; /* localhost */
    const char* portname="daytime";
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=0;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    struct addrinfo* res=0;
    if (fd == 0) {
        int err=getaddrinfo(hostname,portname,&hints,&res);
        if (err!=0) {
            cout << "ERROR: sendUDP() getaddrinfo(): " << err < endl;
            exit(err);
        }
        fd=socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
        if (fd==-1) {
            cout << "ERROR: sendUDP() socket(): " << errno < endl;
            exit(errno);
        }
    }
    if (sendto(fd,pDat,sizeof(BfdDat),0,
    res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)==-1) {
    exit(errno);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

**Rx**:

```
void network::RxDatTh(void)
{
    cout << "In Rx Thread" << endl;
    BfdDat UDPData;
    struct sockaddr_storage src_addr;
    socklen_t src_addr_len;
    const char* hostname=0; /* wildcard */
    const char* portname="daytime";
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=0;
    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE|AI_ADDRCONFIG;
    struct addrinfo* res=0;
    int err=getaddrinfo(hostname,portname,&hints,&res);
    if (err!=0) {
        cout << "ERROR In Rx Thread: after getaddrinfo()" << endl;
        exit(err);
    }

    int fd=socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    if (fd==-1) {
        cout << "ERROR In Rx Thread: after socket()" << endl;
        exit(errno);
    }
    if (bind(fd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen)==-1) {
        cout << "ERROR In Rx Thread: after bind():" << errno << endl;
        exit(errno);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);
    cout << "In Rx Thread: after freeaddrinfo()" << endl;



    src_addr_len=sizeof(src_addr);
    while (true) {
        cout << "waiting for Data..." << endl;
        ssize_t count=recvfrom(fd,&UDPData,sizeof(BfdDat),0,(struct sockaddr*)&src_addr,&src_addr_len);
        if (count==-1) {
            exit(errno);
        } else if (count==sizeof(BfdDat)) {
            warn("datagram too large for UDPData: truncated");
        } else {
            cout << "succesfully received UDPData" << endl;
        }     
    }
}
```

Mind, these two methods get executed in separate thread scopes.

Comment: What synchronization do you have between these two threads? If none, then if the send thread runs before the receive thread, the datagram will go nowhere. (Can you paste the exact output you get? Can you show us how these threads are started?)

Comment: the datagram is repeatedly sent every 1 second and then Rx thread is started before the Tx thread becomes alive.

Comment: Since none of that is in the code you've shown, I'm not sure how you are expecting people to help you. You haven't given them enough code to replicate the error and lots of code you haven't shared could cause the exact problem you've described.

Comment: Is this the real code? Are you really creating a new socket per send? And never closing it? And suffering FD exhaustion? And leaking the addrinfo? And not telling us?

Comment: @EJP I've updated my function, added `fd` as a private clas member and will create the socket only when it's 0, see above+ `close()` it in the destructor